# Unit testing ModelState.IsValid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I've been recently dabbling into unit testing and I was wondering if I'm able to unit test one of my controllers in my project, is it possible to add errors or imitate an invalid ModelState?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add errors to the `ModelState` by using

```
ModelState.AddModelError("key", "exception");
```

More information can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

I Hope this helps.